# border-radius not working consistently in similar divs in chrome

Tags: html, css

The [website I'm working on](https://buttercms.com) has a div on the right showing code examples in the hero section of the homepage. We use a similar div on one of our landing pages (https://buttercms.com/l/ruby-blog-software/) but the bottom of the div doesnt have rounded borders.

I can't figure out why the landing page div doesnt have rounded borders but the homepage div does.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: And use developer tools to inspect the difference in style properties and where they come from.

Comment: It does have rounded corners on both pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only did it at certain breakpoints and only on one of my monitors.

The `<pre>` only showed up on the same breakpoints the border was wrong

The solution that worked for me was

```css
body.landing_page .code-examples .code-container .code pre {
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    min-height: 320px;
}
```

The original border radius was 0px